# Rails doesnt recognize existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to set up a simple CRUD using an existing (not rails-made) mysql database. I used scaffold to set up the necessary files, and edited the '_form' file to match my table.

But when i open the site in a browser and click 'new', fill out the form, click sibmit, i get an error: `NoMethodError in ContactsController#create    -   undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`

As if it doesnt recognize the database, right? And there is a matching model because i used scaffold.

Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE

---

I cant run `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:schema:load` because the database is already in existence.

If i go to console and type `Contact` (name of the table im working with) it says `NameError: uninitialized constant Contacts` but if i type `Contact.new` it says `#<Contact idContact: nil, name: nil, address: nil, email: nil, phones: nil, investment_advisor: nil>` meaning it does find the table because those are the table's columns

Comment: I assume you ran rake db:migrate? Can you run rake db:schema:load? What happens when you open a rails console and type Contact.new?

Comment: It would be wise to post your #create method here, but from the looks of it, you're not instantiating a Contact somehow.

Comment: Could you please show the update/create action from controller and the form code? and the model or db table structure would be nice to see to to find the reasons

Comment: This isn't enough information. Do your models match the table defs?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're getting `blah blah blah ... nil:NilClass` you're referencing a `nil` object when you're expecting a value to not be nil. Debug for that, and go from there.

Other than that, dealing with existing databases should be fine, so long as you either name your models appropriately (to match existing table names, so the rest of the automatic ActiveRecord stuff will work), [or specify the table names in the models](http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-model-working-legacy-database) in the case where the existing database doesn't follow Rails naming conventions.

Comment: Hmm .. Is there any command i have to do to get the rails project to recognize all the tables?

Comment: You have to specify the table names in the models themselves (see the link). My guess is that your existing DB doesn't follow Rails naming conventions, so you just have to help Rails out a little bit and say, "This [insert your model name] connects to table `xyz`"

Comment: Im pretty sure i did the models correct, but how do i find the correct naming convention? The first letter of the tables names are capital, is that a problem?

Comment: Naming it "contacts", you should be safe what naming concerns!

Comment: Let's say you have a model called "PostComment" that represents a comment on a blog post. The Rails convention would make the table all lower case, and pluralized => `post_comments`. If, instead, your existing table is called `PostComments`, then in the `PostComment` model class you write `set_table_name "PostComments"` <= the exact naming and capitalization, as it exists in the actual DB - the link has more examples and details on connecting apps to legacy databases. If you don't do this, Rails will look for a non-capitalized, pluralized table by default. You're overriding that default.